# how to install pod without disturbing previous pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 10.3, If I install one pod,It is installing but previous pods are updating.Tell me way to install pod without updating remaining pods.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set exact version to old pods like `pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '3.0'`. You can list versions of current pods using `cat Podfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to run `pod install`. Unlike `pod update`, it will read the `Podfile.lock` to keep existing Pods at the same version.